# SQL LIKE - Using square bracket (character range) matching to match an entire word

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

In REGEX you can do something like [a-c]+, which will match on

- aaabbbccc
- abcccaabc
- cbccaa
- b
- aaaaaaaaa

In SQL LIKE it seems that one can either do the equivalent of ".*" which is "%", or [a-c]. Is it possible to use the +(at least one) quantifier in SQL to do [a-c]+?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the desired end-query would look something like

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '[a-c]+'

which would then match on the list above, but would NOT match on e.g "xxxxxaxxxx"

Comment: The sql server function that plays with regex is called `patindex()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, SQL Server's `LIKE` patterns are much weaker than regular expressions.  For your particular example, you can do:

```
where col not like '%[^a-c]%'
```

That is, the column contains no characters that are not a, b, or c.

Comment: While my actual problem is a lot more complex and this answer doesn't help, for the simplified problem I described in the question, this is a valid answer.

Comment: @KornélRegius . . . You should ask another question with more detail about your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in SQL with combination of LIKE e.g :

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE '%[^a-z0-9 .]%'
```

This works in SQL

Or in your case

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE '%[^a-c]%'
```

Comment: I wonder, did you mean "NOT LIKE"? So   SELECT * FROM #table WHERE data NOT LIKE '%[^a-c]%'

Comment: Yes, if you need to select everything that doesn't containt a-c.

Answer (score -3):

I seems you want some data from database, That is you don't know exactly, You must show your column and the all character that you want in that filed.

Comment: Use the comment section if you need further information about the question.